# Export a wordpress blog to a wiki

Tags: wiki

I have a wordpress blog and the posts would better suit a wiki format becuase I want to make them open to editing.

Is there a way to conveniently export my posts so they can be imported by MediaWiki or another common Wiki application?

Comment: Gran rights for users to edit posts. If you want to make posts open for editing only no need to migrate to wiki.

Comment: I am interested in the ability to see the history of edits and I'm not sure if granting access to users to edit posts is good in case content gets lost or spammed and the content already exists so adding wiki functionality kind of means I will be adding another layer if you see what I mean.

Comment: This is a *user support* question, involving *user content*, that would be better-directed to the [official wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exporting them to a dedicated Wiki platform, have you considered [one of the plugins that add wiki functionality to an existing WordPress platform](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/wiki)?

Answer (score 1):

The exported XML file is basically all of your posts in HTML format, with some wrapper XML to delineate each post.  So, here is a three-step solution:

1. Extract the HTML of each post from the exported XML file. Use regex, copy and paste, or some [XML Transformation](http://oreilly.com/catalog/orxmlapp/chapter/ch07.pdf) magic.
2. Convert HTML to MediaWiki markup. Search Google for [ mediawiki import html ] or the HTML2wikipedia Home Page for more information.
3. [Import the resulting file(s)](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aImport) into your installation of MediaWiki. After using the tools above, you will likely have either MediaWiki markup or an XML file.

   - If you have MediaWiki markup, then you want to do a "Transwiki" import
   - If you have a Mediawiki XML file, then you want to do an "Upload" import

If you are using another wiki platform, then this will change slightly, since all the major wiki platforms have a similar approach to markup.

Happy coding!
James

P.S.  Sorry for the references without links.  I'm new to StackExchange, so I could only post two hyperlinks.